# Unexpected behaviour with bs4 and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

This is a minimal reproducible example of my code:

```
def get_results(num_of_new, soup, driver):    

    ...

    for i in range(num_of_new):
    ...
        try:
        
            btn = inner[i].find_element_by_name("Bedömda kunskapskrav") #inner is a list of selenium elements
            btn.click()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
            rows = soup.find_all("tr", class_="value")
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
            print(soup)
            print(soup2)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        output.append(result) #output is just a list

    return output
```

When I print both soup and soup2 I get two different outputs. Soup2 contains tr tags with a class attribute of "value" while soup doesn't. I thought it might have to do with the fact that `get_result`'s parameter is named soup, but after googling I no longer think so. Can anyone help me and figure out why I get two different outputs from `soup` and `soup2`?

Comment: Is it just a matter of timing? Perhaps add in a wait condition?

Comment: I added a few `time.sleep` and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps consider using a selenium method https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html This would allow for a more controlled timing and potentially earlier exit.